# from two way data binding to one way databinding angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive

```
<directive dataset="dataObject"></directive>
```

my directive link function have something like this:

```
var oldData = '';

var initFunction = function(){
  oldData = scope.dataObject;
}

scope.reset = function(){
  scope.dataObject = oldData;
};
```

The problem is that when i modify the data in some way, when i want to reset the dataobject to its default value before modifying but everytime i do this, the two way databinding its messing my data, now the problem is that this is for a plot so the data is modified all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `angular.copy` to create "other reference"

```
var initFunction = function(){
  oldData = angular.copy(scope.dataObject);
}
```